# cant read the object using $(card.type)

Tags: javascript

i tried creating a app thing using document.createElement()
i made a div (for a card)
i used `card.innerHtml = '<h3>$(card.type)</h3>'`
and it said $(card.type)

i tried
`card.innerHtml = '<p>' + card.type + '</p>';`
but it said undefined

this is the full code

```
const rarity =["common", "uncommon", "rare", "epic", "legendary", "special"]
const number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" , "9", "10"]

var randomType = Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)
var randomrarity = Math.floor(Math.random() * rarity.length)
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length)

cardEl = document.getElementById('cardonhand')

var card = {
    type : type[randomType],
    rarity :rarity[randomrarity],
    number :number[randomnumber]
}

console.log(card)

var card = document.createElement("div")
    card.innerHTML = '<h3>' + card.type + '</h3>';

    cardEl.appendChild(card);

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 70) {
        location.reload();
    }
})
```

Comment: wait i forgot the first line ```const type = ["rock", "paper", "scissor",]```

Comment: Inserting variables into strings is done with `${variable}` and the string has to be delimited by backticks: `\``. Also, you are redeclaring `card`. Just look at `card.innerHTML = '<h3>' + card.type + '</h3>';` The first card is the element, the second card is your variable. You need to rename one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Your function fails because you use the same variable name for `card` twice.
One for the object with `type`, `rarity` and `number`
One for the `div` element. As soon as you assign the new `div` element to your variable `card`, the initial object is gone, forever. So the new `card` is a DOM element and does not have the `type` property of the initial object anymore. That's why it says `undefined`.

A working example of your code, in which the `card` object variable is renamed tot `cardObj`:

```
<div id="cardonhand"></div>
<script>
const type = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
const rarity =["common", "uncommon", "rare", "epic", "legendary", "special"]
const number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" , "9", "10"]

var randomType = Math.floor(Math.random() * type.length)
var randomrarity = Math.floor(Math.random() * rarity.length)
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length)

var cardEl = document.getElementById('cardonhand');

var cardObj = {
    type : type[randomType],
    rarity :rarity[randomrarity],
    number :number[randomnumber]
}

console.log(cardObj)

var card = document.createElement("div")
    card.innerHTML = '<h3>' + cardObj.type + '</h3>';

    cardEl.appendChild(card);

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 70) {
        location.reload();
    }
}) 
</script>
```